# Earth's direction in space

Tags: reference-frames, earth, relative-motion

After watching videos about the rotation of the planets being helical and not heliocentric, I wondered, as Earth travels through space, which part of Earth is the forefront?

Comment: I will respond via comment because I am just referring to a link: http://www.slate.com/blogs/bad_astronomy/2013/03/04/vortex_motion_viral_video_showing_sun_s_motion_through_galaxy_is_wrong.html

Comment: Since the earth rotates, the forefront does a full 360 every 24 hours, or, 24 hours 4 minutes, which is closer to the absolute rotation (the observed rotation doesn't take the orbit around the sun into account - that subtracts 4 minutes), or maybe it adds 4 minutes.  I can never keep that straight.    The best way to measure-absolute speed is by cosmic background radiation.  http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap090906.html

Comment: @userLTK wow that's a fantastic image. I'd never heard of the Great Attractor before. Maybe you can somehow work this up into an answer - it's certainly relevant.

Comment: I had to look up the great attractor myself - it's pretty awesome, but since I'd only just now read about it, I probobly shouldn't try to make an answer about it.   I know you're not supposed to post youtube here, but I rather enjoyed this explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9qeOhJ9dbg

Comment: @userLTK There's no prohibition on youtube here. The only problem with it is when a question or actual answer (not just a comment) says "watch this video" and leaves it at that, forcing users to spend 5, 10, 85 minutes watching something to see what could have been summarized in a few paragraphs at most.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define the direction of motion of the Solar system as the direction of motion relative to the [cosmic microwave background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) i.e. the direction defined by the [dipole anisotropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#CMBR_dipole_anisotropy). Suppose the Solar system is moving in the plane of the ecliptic as shown in (a):

[image: Motion of Solar System]

In that case no particular part of the Earth is in the forefront of the velocity. Because the Earth rotates about its axis, and about the Sun, every point on Earth gets its turn as the leading edge.

Suppose the Solar system is moving normal to the plane of the ecliptic as shown in (b) above, then all the points within the Artic circle (or Antarctic circle if it's moving in the other direction) get their turn as the leading edge. No point outside the Arctic/Antarctic circle will be the leading point.

In fact the Solar system is moving at about 10° to the plane of the ecliptic on the North side - [see this article](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~huterer/PRESS/CMB_Huterer.pdf) (2MB PDF) for more details.

[image: Motion]

Although not in the plane of the ecliptic, this angle is less than the axial tilt of the Earth. So every point on Earth is at some time the leading point.